# returning Catch block error to View from Model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i'm new to MVC 3. i am trying to insert data at model layer but it doesn't insert any data. 
***ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.*** and during debugging Constr parameter of ConnectDb method accepts conection string but couldn't be used in body of function, returns null. I tried with web.config too.

CODE:

VIEW:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("register","Home", FormMethod.Post, new {id="submitForm"})) 
{

   <div>
    <i>@Html.Label("Name:")</i>
       @Html.TextBox("txtboxName")
   </div>

   <div>
    <i>@Html.Label("Email:")</i>
       @Html.TextBox("txtboxEmail")
   </div>

   <div>  
    <i>@Html.Label("Password:")</i>
       @Html.Password("txtboxPassword")
   </div>

   <div>  
    <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="Command" value="Submit">Submit</button> 
   </div>


}
```

Controller:

```
namespace LoginSys.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Registration";

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult register(string command, FormCollection formData ) 
        {
            if (command == "Submit") 
            {
                var name  = formData["txtboxName"];
                var email = formData["txtboxEmail"];
                var pwd   = formData["txtboxPassword"];
                String conStr = "Data Source=HUNAIN-PC;Initial Catalog=registration;User ID=sa;Password=abc123!@#";

                database db = new database();
                db.connectDB(name, email, pwd, conStr);
                ViewBag.Message = conStr;


            }
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

model:

```
public ConnectionStatus connectDB(String name, String email, String pwd, String conStr)
        {
            var con = conStr;
            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(con);
            SqlCommand sqlCom =new SqlCommand(con);
          //  sqlCom.Connection = sqlCon;
            sqlCom.CommandText = "insert into tblRegister (Name, Email, Pwd) values (@name, @email, @pwd)";
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", pwd);
            ConnectionStatus connectStatus = new ConnectionStatus();
            int row_aff;
            try
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
                row_aff = sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connectStatus.Message = "OK";

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                connectStatus.Message = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlCon.Close();
            }
            return connectStatus;
```

Error: ***ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.***
i found a problem during debugging that my method COnnectDb accepts ConnectionString as a parameter in 'Constr' but it can't be assigned or used in functions body i.e. `var con = conStr;` is null and every other variable in which i use Constr parameter is NULL, Why ?

```
![enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Using ViewBag, TempData,.. you could be able to return data from server-side to the client. These are temporary memories like Session.

Comment: You can return Content(ex.Message) also.

Comment: how sir how ? please if u can edit my code 

Viewbag not working or appearing in model intellisense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Why not inserting data into tbl ?

Because you never initialized the SqlConnection of the command:

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(con);
SqlCommand sqlCom =new SqlCommand(con);
```

The `sqlCon` variable here is not related to the command. The correct way to initialize a command is this:

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(con);
SqlCommand sqlCom = sqlCon.CreateCommand();
```

This being said read below for a complete example of the proper way to design this.

> 2) catch(Exception ex) { // how to return ex.message or error to VIEW ? }

You could have your `connectDB` method (erm `connectDB` for something that's inserting???) return potential errors as `out` parameter. Also wrap those IDisposable resources in `using` statements or you might be leaking resources pretty badly:

```
public bool TryInsertUser(string name, string email, string pwd, string conStr, out string error)
{
    error = null;
    using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(conStr)
    using (var sqlCom = sqlCon.CreateCommand())
    {
        sqlCon.Open();
        sqlCom.CommandText = "insert into tblRegister (Name, Email, Pwd) values (@name, @email, @pwd)";
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", pwd);

        try
        {
            sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            error = ex.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and then write a view model:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    public string Command { get; set; }
    public string TxtboxName { get; set; } // <-- Find better name
    public string TxtboxEmail { get; set; } // <-- Find better name
    public string TxtboxPassword { get; set; } // <-- Find better name
}
```

that your controller action will take as parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model) 
{
     if (model.Command == "Submit") 
     {
         // TODO: This usually goes into your web.config
         string conStr = "Data Source=HUNAIN-PC;Initial Catalog=registration;User ID=sa;Password=abc123!@#";

         database db = new database();
         string error;
         if (!db.TryInsertUser(model.TxtboxName, model.TxtboxEmail, model.TxtboxPassword, conStr, out error))
         {
             // Some error occurred while attempting to insert the record
             // in the database -> we are adding this error to the ModelState
             // so that it can be displayed in the view
             ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
         }
    }
    return View();
}
```

and then inside your view you could use the `Html.ValidationSummary()` helper to display potential error messages.

Comment: error: ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

Comment: Did you try the code shown in my answer? I suspect you haven't because the code in your question you don't initialize the connection of the command. Look more carefully how I have wrapped the sql connection and command in using statements and how the sql command is created from the connection. Now do the same. Basically in your question you have this : `SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand(con);` which should be replaced with `SqlCommand sqlCom = sqlCon.CreateCommand()` as shown in my answer. See the difference?

Comment: @James, did you manage to get that working by following the example in my answer?

Comment: wowwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww. it's done. Amazing. One last thing that i should ask.

Comment: the difference between SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand();
                       sqlCom.Connection = sqlCon;

and SqlCommand sqlCom = sqlCon.CreateCommand()

Comment: please answer that last question that would lead towards closing this topic by marking answers :)

Comment: @James, those are equivalent. You could use one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to trace yourself what is the error, it's too many possibility to that.

for error handling, there are many ways to do that, you can see on this article: [Error Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397417%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.